# how to hide parameter from url

Tags: apache, perl, .htaccess

I have this url:
http://localhost:8080/cgi-bin/gestionale/dashboard.pl?user=santaclaus
My question is how to convert this:
http://localhost:8080/cgi-bin/gestionale/dashboard.pl?user=santaclaus
in
http://localhost:8080/cgi-bin/gestionale/dashboard.pl

I can modify with rewrite rule on my .htaccess file? If the Answer is yes please explain me how to do.

Comment: What if it was a different user? How is the Perl supposed to distinguish between users if the username isn't there?

Comment: Why do you feel the need to hide the username in the URL anyway? (This is probably a http://xyproblem.info/ )

Comment: @Quentin 
for security reasons i need to hide the username. If i change the username santaclaus with another user i access in her data.

Comment: @Python_96 then I'm afraid your problem is bigger than hiding the user from the URL. You should research for a proper user authentication / login solution, not for hiding the username.

Comment: @eballes yes, but i use the method:  use CGI::Session ( '-ip_match' ); and i don't know use method cookies.

Comment: If you are relying on the user supplied URL for auth, then your code is dangerously broken. There is no solution to this, that isn't 'do it properly' and that's a code rewrite.

Comment: @Python_96 — Nobody said anything about cookies … and CGI::Session is implemented using cookies anyway.

Answer (score 5):

> for security reasons i need to hide the username. If i change the username santaclaus with another user i access in her data

Hiding the username won't help you. You still need to determine what username to use in your code, and if it comes from the browser then the operator of the browser can change it.

Since you said "with another user", you must have some kind of login system in place. You have to use that.

There are two approaches you could take:

1. Don't put the username in the URL in the first place. Read it from whatever login system you have with your server side code.
2. Put the username in the URL and have your server side code check to see if the currently logged in user is authorised to access the requested user.

Option 2 is more complex, but allows for admin users to access other users.

Answer (score -4):

There are two types of http request. GET and POST. here you are making GET http request. so your request parameters are visible in the url. To hide it you must use POST. check more details here 'http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp"

Comment: You need to read the comments on the question. A good 10 minutes before you posted your answer, it was clarified that the objective was to stop the user from changing the username. Moving the username to a POST request won't help with that.